# html2canvas giving blank images

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas to take a screenshot of certain components in my react app when I take a screenshot but no matter what I try the images keep turning out to be blank.

This is what the code inside the onClick listener for my screenshot button looks like.

```
            const help = document.querySelector("#help");
            html2canvas(help).then((canvas) => {
              console.log(help, canvas);
              const a = document.createElement("a");
              a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
              a.download = "help.png";
              a.click();
            });
```

This is what #help element contains.

```
      <ul id="help">
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>lorem</li>
        <li>lorem</li>
        <li>lorem</li>
      </ul>
```

The console.log statement shows that the correct element is selected in the querySelector. I've even tried changing around fields like allowTaint, backgroundColor, foreignObjectRendering, useCORS from what I saw on other answers on here but none of these seemed to work for me. Also tried if removing all my custom css might help but even then it wasn't working. Setting logging to true didn't give me any outputs either so I'm pretty much clueless as about where to proceed from here.

Comment: Using `querySelector` with React is a bit suspect. React is a library that has a very specific workflow as to how the DOM is updated/rendered.

Comment: But the element I'm looking for is printed to console exactly as I expect. And also #help is rendered right at the beginning while my screenshot button is rendered later so I don't think it has anything to do with `querySelector` being unable to find the element, unless there's something i missed.

Comment: @AdamJijo did you find any solution for this, I am facing the same issue here?

Answer (score -1):

Try  to use `getElementById` it will work.

```
const getPrint = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('headerr');
    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var imgWidth = 210;
        var pageHeight = 295;
        var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        //window.open(imgData);
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        var position = -2;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        /* add extra pages if the div size is larger than a a4 size */
        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        pdf.save('file.pdf');
    });
};
```

Comment: Using `getElementByID` gave me the same result. Also, I don't get why you're using jsPDF in your answer when I'm not trying to make a pdf.